# Short Term Strategy For Maximising Savings AsAlternative To ISA

Tags: united-kingdom, savings, isa

I have been saving for about 10 years, putting the maximum into a cash ISA every year I have been able. I currently have around £50,000 in there.

In approximately 2 years I plan to buy a property, but between now and then is there a more sensible strategy to handling my savings given the woefully low interest rates on an ISA.

I'm looking for a simple alternative that doesn't involve excessive bureaucracy, risk or time.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is probably too late by now, however since you do not wish to put your savings in higher risk investments, one avenue to look at would be debt instruments. Here also probably you should look at gilt or good quality corporate debt. Another option could be overseas market gilt/debt. For this best would be to subscribe into a mutual fund scheme managed by good fund houses. You could approach any of the good fund houses and look for funds which are debt based and of good quality, they would certainly have many low risk moderate return funds. You could also approach your bank, most of the banks have an investment arm that mutual fund schemes.